# Schedule Messages with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I am using WhatsApp API to send massive messages to users in nodejs, but I would like to add Schedule messages I don't know how I thought about setTimeout but I don't think that this is the best way to do this. Does anyone have any idea? thanks for your answers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron for this. You should create a cron that runs on time you defined time. For example [Nodejs Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) is one of those.